# ¿Qué está mal con este código?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, map

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial donde se ve que compila perfectamente pero cuando yo trato de compilarlo en mi pc me regresa este mensaje:

[image: Mensaje del compilador]

Lo que el programa debe hacer es inicializar un map que guarde cadenas y después agregarle otra después de la inicialización:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        maps()

    }
private fun maps(){
        var myMap: Map<String, Int> = mapOf()
        println(myMap)

        myMap = mutableMapOf()mapOf("Joshua" to 1, "Honda" to 2, "Vento" to 3)
        println(myMap)
        myMap["Italika"] = 4
        myMap.put("harley", 5)


    }
}
```

Nota: Estoy desarrollando con kotlin en android studio en linux

Comment: `mutableMapOf()mapOf("Joshua" to 1, "Honda" to 2, "Vento" to 3)` No deberías cerrar el paréntesis de `mutableMapOf` tras declarar el `mapOf()`?? -> `mutableMapOf(mapOf("Joshua" to 1, "Honda" to 2, "Vento" to 3))`. Tal como lo haces tú, lo único que haces es invocarlo sin parámetros... y luego crear el mapa normal con los 3 nombres, pero no los estás asignando al mutableMap!

Answer (score 0):

Problablemente lo que quieres hacer es crear un map vacío y luego agregarle valores. En ese caso se haría así

```
private fun maps() {
    val myMap = mutableMapOf<String,Int>()
    println(myMap)
    myMap.putAll(mapOf("Joshua" to 1, "Honda" to 2, "Vento" to 3))
    println(myMap)
    myMap["Italika"] = 4
    myMap.put("harley", 5)
    println(myMap)
}
```

En cambio si quieres inicializarlo con valores sería así

```
private fun maps() {
    val myMap = mutableMapOf("Joshua" to 1, "Honda" to 2, "Vento" to 3)
    println(myMap)
    myMap["Italika"] = 4
    myMap.put("harley", 5)
    println(myMap)
}
```

En cualquier caso el map debe ser mutable. En tu ejemplo `var myMap: Map<String, Int> = mapOf()` lo estás declarando como map (inmutable) por lo que nunca podrás agregarle valores